# Reworking a question asked long time ago with already an answer

Tags: support, questions, edits

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699684/python-buildout-get-path-to-the-egg-in-the-recipe-api) in 2014, with a use case illustrating my issue. The answer was not bad, but it was more about my use case than the real question's title.

Today, I have the same issue as specified in the title. If you look on google the words `python buildout get path egg`, this question and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197797/how-to-prepend-a-path-to-a-buildout-generated-script) are in the top 3 results, and in the top 10 google results there is no answer to this question (answer are all non-related).

What should I do ? Rework a post done long time ago, invalid the answer and eventually start a bounty ? Or modify my question to better fit its content, start a new question with the same title and wait for answers ?

Answer (score 2):

If that question's title doesn't accurately reflect the question being asked and answered, then edit the question's title so that it better reflects the content of the post.